# Disable Cppcheck in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cppcheck

VS asked me if I wanted to check the project every I save a file - and I clicked yes...
How do I disable this functions as it costs very much time...

Comment: I'm going to assume you already looked in Options for a way to disable this?

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes. But the settings are an ezyclopedia. I don't know where to look. "Cpp" or "check" doesn't find anything...

Comment: To clarify: this is not a built-in Visual Studio function. You're referring to the cppcheck add-in (https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cppcheck-vs-addin).

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh. Tools -> CPPcheck settings -> uncheck "Check files after save"